# How can Transformers travel in space and survive the cold, given they're susceptible to it in the movies?

Tags: transformers

I was wondering if there's any explanation how Transformers flew to Earth/Moon in space. Watching once again first part of Transformers movies I noticed that Bumblebee/Megatron were kept frozen. At the same time Autobots got to Earth somehow and I didn't see any space ship or something.

Could someone bring a light on that please?

Comment: They crash landed while chasing All Spark...

Comment: Space is not cold.  In fact, a big problem in space is cooling, given that vacuum in space  is as good an insulator as in a thermos.

Comment: This ship was used to facilitate quicker travel. They could have broken free of any gravitational influences except Earth’s gravity, and just fallen towards Earth through space but it might have taken an awful long time, a lot longer than the interstellar voyage with their spaceship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Getting to Earth

The writers were asked this very question on [the old movie message board](https://web.archive.org/web/20071229074114/http://boards.transformersmovie.com/showthread.php?p=388596) (now defunct):

> 1. How did the Autobots travel to earth? During the fight scenes they are incapable of flight - they keep falling to the ground (even Optimus), and when they want to get on top of a building they just climb step by step.
>      Are they now "trapped" on earth?

Their answer:

> 1.) They crossed interstellar space in a larger ship and then entered our orbit in pod-like protoform. We'll let others decide if they're trapped.

We see the Autobot ship The Ark in *Dark of the Moon*, which Optimus explains was the ship that Sentinel Prime had been aboard when he crashed.

[image: The Ark]

We see a similar ship used by Lockdown in *Age Of Extinction*, while the previously canon prequel book [Ghosts of Yesterday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Ghosts_of_Yesterday) mentions The Ark (the Autobot ship) and The Nemesis (The Decepticon ship), however the story was later contradicted by the *Dark of the Moon* details.

### Being frozen on Earth

It's important to remember that Megatron didn't just fly to the Arctic Circle and become immediately stuck/frozen. The ambient cold alone wasn't what trapped him. An already weakened Megatron (lacking energon from traveling and entering the atmosphere) landed and then fell into the water, where he was frozen. This is backed up by the fact that Sector 7 uses liquid nitrogen to keep him frozen at some -320°F. Coupled with the fact that we see Transformers traveling and remaining in space just fine, we can conclude the cold alone is not enough to damage them severely.

[image: Megatron needs food badly. Megatron is about to die.]

[image: Megatron lands in the Arctic]

[image: Megatron gets stuck]

<sup>All scans are from *Transformers: The Movie: The prequel*</sup>

Comment: My concern was temperature differences. Let's say the Moon has ~ -200C (or even less if we are talking about outer space). Megatron was 'trapped' in Arctic at -60 - -80..

Comment: Megatron wasn't just immediately trapped when he reached the arctic; he crashed and was *then* trapped by snow/ice. After being dug out, Sector 7 had to use liquid nitrogen and coolant to keep him frozen.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really the temperature. More that they were constantly kept frozen with the help of liquid that essentially put an ice cover ove them.

If we take a few examples from the films the temperature alone shouldn't hurt them: Optimus being in space in the fourth film, autobots being on the moon in the third film. Decepticons being on mars in the third film and on some planet/moon in the second. All of that without any protectional measures against the cold (not counting the protoform used to travel to earth for any of them).

Thus it is not the temperature but the ice covering that freezes them. Although it could have been a goof out of the writers when they tried to find a way to keep megatron incapacitated and the ice coverage being a lucky coincidence, but that is as far as I know not known, so the coverage with the frozen LIQUID is the only thing that so far looks like the logical explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, when Optimus went to find Quintessa in *Age of Extinction* he is seen frozen in space in the beginning of *The Last Knight*. **But**, the original autobots (Optimus Prime, Iron Hide, Jazz, Rachet, and Bumblebee) all got to earth in escape pods from Cybertron that might have protected them from the cold of space.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This could be a better answer if you included images showing (or quotes describing) the escape pods.

Answer (score -1):

In the first movie Bumblebee is not covered in ice, just rendered incapacitated by the cold temperatures of the nitrogen.  At the end of the movie Megatron is dumped to the deepest part of the ocean where the extreme cold and pressure will keep him entombed.  However, in ROTF Megatron is revived by his fellow Decepticons who are not phased by either at the bottom of the ocean.  Megatron then uses his jet pack to fly to one of Saturn's moons (very quickly I might add).  Again, he is not phased by the near absolute zero temperatures of space.  Heck, even Soundwave spent most of his time in the frigid temps of space orbiting Earth as a satelite in ROTF.  I believe it was just an oversite and to build the story of the first movie and just had to be forgotten about to make the rest of the stories work.  Bottom line, it seems that the Transformers can withstand the absolute coldest temperatures in the universe...but that doesn't explain why they again decided that OP would be frozen in The Last Knight.  Well, that movie was so bad it makes sense that they would screw that up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This just seems to support the question without actually providing an answer; please only post answers that answer the question.  You might want to take the [tour].